# Error: "Cannot open file "20210609.log". The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I've got some third party code that writes to a log file one line at a time using the code below:

```
procedure TLog.WriteToLog(Entry: ansistring);
var
    strFile: string;
    fStream: TFileStream;
    strDT: ansistring;
begin
    if ((strLogDirectory<>'') and (strFileRoot<>'')) then
    begin
        if not(DirectoryExists(strLogDirectory)) then
            ForceDirectories(strLogDirectory);
        strFile:=strLogDirectory + '\' + strFileRoot + '-' + strFilename;
        if FileExists(strFile) then
            fStream:=TFileStream.Create(strFile, fmOpenReadWrite)
        else
            fStream:=TFileStream.Create(strFile, fmCreate);
        fStream.Seek(0, soEnd);
        if blnUseTimeStamp then
            strDT:=formatdatetime(strDateFmt + ' hh:mm:ss', Now) + ' ' + Entry + chr(13) + chr(10)
        else
            strDT:=Entry + chr(13) + chr(10);
        fStream.WriteBuffer(strDT[1], length(strDT));
        FreeandNil(fStream);
    end;
end;
```

This has previously been working fine at a client site but in the last few weeks it is now getting the error in the title.

There is no other process that should have the file open. I suspect it is Anti-Virus but the client claims they have disabled the AntiV and they still get the error.

The error ONLY seems to occur when the code is in a loop and writing lines fast.

WHAT I WANT TO KNOW:
Assuming it is not the Anti-Virus (or similar) causing the problem, could it be due to the operating system not clearing a flag (or something similar) before the next time it tries to write to the file?

Comment: You are missing sharing rights on the `TFileStream` constructors (ie, `fmShareDenyNone`, etc), You should also be protecting the `TFileStream` with `try..finally`. You don't need `DirectoryExists()` before `ForceDirectories()`, it will check for existence internally.

Comment: IIRC, doesn't `fmOpenReadWrite` create the file if it doesn't exist? I'll have to check that...

Comment: Normally not, but beside AV there might be other scanning processes trying to access your file. Second, when the writing of a certain line fails at some point, then as Remy said, you won’t release your filestream and keep the file locked.

Comment: @Remy It's not my code. Since the problem is on opening it to write, I don't think the rights are going to make a difference.

Comment: @R-hoek Since the error occurs while creating the stream, it never gets locked - but good point.

Comment: @Toby The error you are getting is a sharing violation. That is very much a sharing rights issue.  The code is trying to open the file using (or not using) sharing rights that don't match with another open handle to the same file, ie trying to open the file for writing when an existing handle to the file does not share writing access to the file.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I get that, but since it is getting the error when trying to open it to write to it - does it matter?
Also, I just noticed this at the bottom of the help page for TFileStream.Create - "Note: On Windows, the Rights parameter is ignored."
Is that wrong?

Comment: My QUESTION - is not "Why is it getting this error?" I get that something else is blocking it. I'm asking if it could be due to the fact that it is opening and closing the file so often and fast - could there be an issue where the code or file system itself is not closing it before the code returns.

Comment: @Toby Yes, it can matter, that is why I mentioned `fmShareDenyNone` earlier. For example: `fStream := TFileStream.Create(strFile, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyNone);` "*I'm asking if it could be due to the fact that it is opening and closing the file so often and fast*" - No, that is not the problem. There is another open handle to the file, and that handle has sharing rights (not) specified that do not match the rights requested by this `TFileStream`. Use a tool like [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to verify.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Ok but what about my previous observation: I just noticed this at the bottom of the help page for TFileStream.Create - "Note: On Windows, the Rights parameter is ignored." Is that wrong?

Comment: Is your application multi-threaded?

Comment: @Toby No, the documentation is not wrong. The `Rights` parameter is indeed ignored on Windows. But it doesn't matter in this case, since the code is not trying to use that parameter anyway. and sharing rights can be specified in the `Mode` parameter instead, which is being used.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - was not aware of that. Help does not indicate that is allowed.

Comment: Yes it does - my bad: The Mode parameter consists of an open mode and (possibly) a share mode or'ed together.

Comment: @Toby yes, it does: "*The `Mode` parameter consists of an open mode **and (possibly) a share mode or'ed together**.*"

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - no it is not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Ok - I'll tell them to give that a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WHAT I WANT TO KNOW: Assuming it is not the Anti-Virus (or similar) causing the problem, could it be due to the operating system not clearing a flag (or something similar) before the next time it tries to write to the file?

No, this is not a speed issue, or a caching issue.  It is a sharing violation, which means there MUST be another open handle to the same file, where that handle has sharing rights assigned (or lack of) which are incompatible with the rights being requested by this code.

For example, if that other handle is not sharing read+write access, then this code will fail to open the file when creating the `TFileStream` with `fmOpenReadWrite`.  If *any* handle is open to the file, this code will fail when creating the `TFileStream` with `fmCreate`, as that requests *Exclusive* access to the file by default.

I would suggest something more like this instead:

```pascal
procedure TLog.WriteToLog(Entry: AnsiString);
var
  strFile: string;
  fStream: TFileStream;
  strDT: AnsiString;
  fMode: Word;
begin
  if (strLogDirectory <> '') and (strFileRoot <> '') then
  begin
    ForceDirectories(strLogDirectory);
    strFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(strLogDirectory) + strFileRoot + '-' + strFilename;
    fMode := fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyWrite;
    if not FileExists(strFile) then fMode := fMode or fmCreate;
    fStream := TFileStream.Create(strFile, fMode);
    try
      fStream.Seek(0, soEnd);
      if blnUseTimeStamp then
        strDT := FormatDateTime(strDateFmt + ' hh:mm:ss', Now) + ' ' + Entry + sLineBreak
      else
        strDT := Entry + sLineBreak;
      fStream.WriteBuffer(strDT[1], Length(strDT));
    finally
      fStream.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

However, do note that using `FileExists()` introduces a [TOCTOU race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).  The file might be deleted/created by someone else after the existence is checked and before the file is opened/created.  Best to let the OS handle this for you.

At least on Windows, you can use [`CreateFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) directly with the `OPEN_ALWAYS` flag (`TFileStream` only ever uses `CREATE_ALWAYS`, `CREATE_NEW`, or `OPEN_EXISTING`), and then assign the resulting `THandle` to a `THandleStream`, eg:

```pascal
procedure TLog.WriteToLog(Entry: AnsiString);
var
  strFile: string;
  hFile: THandle;
  fStream: THandleStream;
  strDT: AnsiString;
begin
  if (strLogDirectory <> '') and (strFileRoot <> '') then
  begin
    ForceDirectories(strLogDirectory);
    strFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(strLogDirectory) + strFileRoot + '-' + strFilename;
    hFile := CreateFile(PChar(strFile), GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
    if hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
    try
      fStream := THandleStream.Create(hFile);
      try
        fStream.Seek(0, soEnd);
        if blnUseTimeStamp then
          strDT := FormatDateTime(strDateFmt + ' hh:mm:ss', Now) + ' ' + Entry + sLineBreak
        else
          strDT := Entry + sLineBreak;
        fStream.WriteBuffer(strDT[1], Length(strDT));
      finally
        fStream.Free;
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(hFile);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

In any case, you can use a tool like [SysInternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to verify if there is another handle open to the file, and which process it belongs to.  If the offending handle in question is being closed before you can see it in PE, then use a tool like [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to log access to the file in real-time and check for overlapping attempts to open the file.

Comment: The code that call the WriteToLog has an exception handler that also calls WriteTolog 8-) and it is able to write the exception - so whatever it is, it is not locking the file for long. I've used Process Explorer (love ProcExp) but was not able to see anything. Was not aware of Process Monitor. Will tell them to try that!

Comment: As ALWAYS - incredibly helpful! (and patient)

Comment: BTW: 
fStream := THandleCreate.Create(hFile); 
s/b
fStream := THandleSTREAM.Create(hFile);